# Errors while building an android project in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to build an android project in unity but whenever i tries build it fails i have installed jdk and android sdk but then also it fails please anyone tell what is problem

Comment: could you provide in your question  the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Comment: Are you building an Unity project to android target? Which type of error? Can you add at least the log error?

Comment: what error does it give you on fail? anything from the console? anything to narrow it down